# Can't increase density on a small object

Tags: shaders

This is a newbie question but I've searched all over and can't find a solution.

I'm following this tutorial to create procedural clouds and it works perfectly
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhMQN4vVMIU

But I'd like to add these clouds to a small scene, which has been created using BlenderGIS and then scaled right down. I've scaled it down so that camera depth of field can give the scene a 'model village' type of look. At full size, depth of field has no effect because the scale is massive.

When I scale the clouds down, they become almost completely transparent, seemingly no matter how high I set density.

This image is a copy from the YouTube link showing the shader (the missing bits to the left are texture coordinate and random noise).

[image]

It's the principled volume step that causes the cloud to go almost completely transparent when small. Without that it works, but the cloud doesn't have a nice density effect.

Is there a way to make a cloud like this very small and maintain the density? I found references to 'Density Scale' in the user manual prior to 2.8 but not sure if that's what I want and I can't find references to it anywhere in 2.8.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). Don't forget to bump up sample count in *Render > Volumetrics*. They're set pretty low by default.

Comment: That seems to have cracked it, thanks. I couldn't find a setting anywhere that made a difference!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to bump up the sample count in *Render > Volumetrics > Samples*.
They're set pretty low by default.

[image]

Comment: For anyone else stuck on the same problem, Jachym's tip helped but I also needed to change 'End' in volumetrics to a much smaller number to finally deal with the issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :). I don't work much with Eevee, so any feedback is appreciated.